# Matching rownumber and column name of a data frame with values of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample data frame

```
samp_df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,3,5,7,9),x2=c(2,4,6,8,10))

> samp_df
  x1 x2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  5  6
4  7  8
5  9 10
```

I have another data frame which contains variable str and sis_str

```
samp2_df <- data.frame(str=c(x1,x1,x2,x2,x1),sis_str=c(1,2,4,5,3))

> samp2_df
  str sis_str
1   x1       1
2   x1       2
3   x2       4
4   x2       5
5   x1       3
```

The objective is to create another variable "sim" in the samp2_df data frame which contains the value from samp_df,such that the variable sis_str should match the row name of the first data frame and variable str should match the column name of the first data frame

So the output should be

```
> samp2_df
  str sis_str  sim
1   1       1   1
2   1       2   3
3   2       4   8
4   2       5   10
5   1       3   5
```

Comment: How does your `str` column change in `samp2_df` from `x1, x1, x2....` to `1, 1, 2...` ?

Comment: something like this `samp2_df$sim <- ifelse(samp2_df$str == "x1", samp_df[samp2_df$sis_str, "x1"], samp_df[samp2_df$sis_str, "x2"])`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the column name will remain as x1, x2 etc..

Comment: In that case , I think `mapply(function(x, y) samp_df[x, y], samp2_df$sis_str, samp2_df$str)` should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a two-column matrix as an argument to "[" would be considerably faster if this were a problem of any size. See `?"["` ofor more information on this strategy:

```
samp_df[ cbind(samp2_df$sis_str, as.numeric(samp2_df$str)) ]
[1]  1  3  8 10  5
```

Then just `cbind` that to samp2_df:

```
cbind(samp2_df, sim=samp_df[ cbind(samp2_df$sis_str, as.numeric(samp2_df$str)) ] )
  str sis_str sim
1  x1       1   1
2  x1       2   3
3  x2       4   8
4  x2       5  10
5  x1       3   5
```

:Edit: If instead the task is to match to the rownames rather than the "numbers" (which I took to be the integer indices) then this would succeed:

```
cbind(samp2_df, sim2=samp_df[ cbind(match(samp2_df$sis_str,rownames(samp_df)),
                                    as.numeric(samp2_df$str)) ] )
  str sis_str sim sim2
1   1       1   1    1
2   1       2   3    3
3   2       4   8    8
4   2       5  10   NA
5   1      23  NA    9
```

Comment: there is one thing where this solution is not working. Lets say samp_df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,3,5,7,9),x2=c(2,4,6,8,10)) rownames(samp_df) <- c(1,2,3,4,23) samp2_df <- data.frame(str=c(1,1,2,2,1),sis_str=c(1,2,4,5,23)) In this case for sis_str 23 I am getting the sim value as null although ideally it should be 9

Comment: If you give the "[" function a value that is beyond the range of valid indexing then it should return a "subscript out of bounds error". If you wanted to match rownames, then you should have posed that as the question. You in fact asked for matching to row numbers.

Comment: yes that's my fault, I should have mentioned rownames.. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: So the question is probably answered now.

Comment: No not really, I had accepted the answer before checking for the rowname scenario, I would really appreciate if you could provide a solution. This is the scenario samp_df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,3,5,7,9),x2=c(2,4,6,8,10))
  
  rownames(samp_df) <- c(1,2,3,4,23)
  
  samp2_df <- data.frame(str=c(1,1,2,2,1),sis_str=c(1,2,3,4,23))   As you already mentioned the above solution will not work for rowname, so need your inputs here

Comment: 8 hours ago, I gave you an edit to my answer that as far as I can tell fully addresses the new situation. You haven't responded to that edit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a better way but one way to do this is by using `mapply`. We create a row-column pair value to be extracted form `samp_df` where the row value is `samp2_df$sis_str` and the column value is the numeric part in `samp2_df$str` which we get by substituting the character values to empty strings (`""`).

```
samp2_df$sim <- mapply(function(x, y) samp_df[x, y], 
               samp2_df$sis_str, as.numeric(sub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", samp2_df$str)))

samp2_df
#  str sis_str sim
#1  x1       1   1
#2  x1       2   3
#3  x2       4   8
#4  x2       5  10
#5  x1       3   5
```

Comment: I should have thought about mapply, yeah this makes sense, i was trying to do this with match.. Thanks!

Comment: One thing though if my sis_str variable is factor then cbind is giving incorrect results, i.e. it is converting samp2_df$sis_str value to literal row number of the data frame. Any solution for this?

Comment: @bakas even if it is factor it still gives me the same result as shown.

Comment: For me it worked after i converted to numeric, but there is one thing where this solution is not working. Lets say samp_df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,3,5,7,9),x2=c(2,4,6,8,10))
  
  rownames(samp_df) <- c(1,2,3,4,23)
  
  samp2_df <- data.frame(str=c(1,1,2,2,1),sis_str=c(1,2,4,5,23)) In this case for sis_str 23 I am getting the sim value as null although ideally it should be 9..

Comment: @bakas how should it be 9? For rest of the `sis_str` values you compare it with row number and for 23 you compare it with row names? You should be consistent with your requirements.